# Is there a way to make this series of autofiltering more elegant?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a ton of filters I need to accomplish, but it ends up in a massive amount of code blocks that seem like they're able to be truncated.

How could I minimize all of this:

```
        .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="xxxxxx"
        .Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(lr, 5)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = .Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(lr, 3)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .Cells.Autofiler

        .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="xxxxxx"
        .Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(lr, 3)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "FULL ACCOUNT UPGRADE"
        .Cells.AutoFilter
        .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="xxxxxx"
        .Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(lr, 3)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "LIGHT ACCOUNT ESTABLISHED"
        .Cells.AutoFilter

            .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="xxxxxx", Criteria2:="xxxxxx2"
            .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=27, Criteria1:="YES"
            .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="Public"
            .Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(lr, 3)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "LIGHT ACCOUNT ESTABLISHED"
            .Cells.AutoFilter

                .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="xxxxxx", Criteria2:="Light Enablement through Payment Proposal"
                .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=27, Criteria1:="YES"
                .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="Private"
                .Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(lr, 3)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "ACTIVATED FOR AFTER FULL USE TRR WAS SENT/ACCEPTED"
                .Cells.AutoFilter

                    .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="xxxxxx", Criteria2:="xxxxxx2"
                    .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=27, Criteria1:="NO"
                    .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="Private"
                    .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=66, Criteria1:="YES"
                    .Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(lr, 3)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "ACTIVATED FOR -- PO SENT BUT NOT RESPONDED TO"
                    .Cells.AutoFilter
                    .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="xxxxxx", Criteria2:="xxxxxx2"
                    .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=27, Criteria1:="NO"
                    .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="Private"
                    .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=66, Criteria1:="NO"
                    .Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(lr, 3)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "ACTIVATED FOR -- PO NOT SENT"
                    .Cells.AutoFilter
```

Comment: This is more of a code review question. Saying that, is the sheet where you are trying to apply these filters in the same workbook as your code?

Comment: @Zac yes, there is a `with` statement above that I didn't include, but it explicitly references the correct workbook/worksheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new sub or function with just the three lines that repeat in the current code. Define parameters for the things that change. Then call the sub/function for each set of parameters. Something like

```
'call the sub/function from other code
DoAutoFilterArray ws, 5, "xxxxxx", Cells(2, 5), Cells(lr, 5), Cells(2, 3), Cells(lr, 3)
DoAutoFilterString ws, 18, "xxxxxx", Cells(2, 3), Cells(lr, 3), "FULL ACCOUNT UPGRADE"

Sub DoAutoFilterArray(ws as Worksheet, filterField as Long, criteria as String, _
                 sourceCell1 as Range, sourceCell2 as Range, _
                 targetCell1 as Range, targetCell2 as Range)

  With ws
    .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=filterField, Criteria1:=criteria
    .Range(sourceCell1, sourceCell2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = .Range(targetCell1, targetCell2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    .Cells.Autofiler
  End With
End Sub

Sub DoAutoFilterString(ws as Worksheet, filterField as Long, criteria as String, _
                 sourceCell1 as Range, sourceCell2 as Range, _
                 targetValue as String)

  With ws
    .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=filterField, Criteria1:=criteria
    .Range(sourceCell1, sourceCell2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = targetValue
    .Cells.Autofiler
  End With
End Sub
```